# Display Name Doesn't Appear Below Large Icon/Tile In Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

1. In Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 -> Create New Project -> Blank App (Universal Windows)
2. Let's call it "Test"
3. Run the Progran.

Now I go to Start Menu on the lower left I choose "All Apps". I see my "Test", I right click it and choose "Pin To Start".

Now within the big tiles on the right side of the start menu, I see my new app's icon but it doesn't show the name beneath it like all the other tiles there.

I looked inside my Package.appxmanifest and under it the DisplayName is set.. so not sure what else I'm missing.

```
<uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="Test"
        ...
</uap:VisualElements>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ensure that you've checked off "Show Name" in the package.appxmanifest and enter a name in there for what you want displayed.

[image]